# Drupal 6: Trying to print Primary links with children, having a hard time

Tags: drupal

I am creating a custom Drupal theme for Drupal 6 and have been struggling all day to get the primary links to print with the child objects.

There are hundreds of possible solutions around, but not one of them work. I must be doing something wrong.

Here is what I would like:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Sub of 1</li>
    </ul>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is no matter what I do I am only getting the top level links. I cannot put the primary links in a block, which most solutions require.

Thank you

Comment: The answer by maged adel below is right up to a point, but if you want to strip the classes Drupal will add to the menu you'll need to use the [menu_tree_page_data()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_page_data/6) function and build up the HTML from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/node/68578
hop that will help u